# About eclipse/maven 's resource folder

Tags: eclipse, spring, hibernate, maven

we could make a resource folder in eclipse and to put hibernate/spring config file in.

when we compile to war, where those resource really be putted in war file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

resource folder will be merged with corresponding sourced packages.

like if you have source code under **src** folder in package **com.mycomp.mypkg** and your config file under **resource** folder in same package then maven will put your code and config file in same package in war.

explained in detail [here](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/examples/adding-filtering-webresources.html)